# Equivalent of URLDownloadToFile for JSON

Tags: c++, html, json

URLDownloadToFile downloads the HTML data of the URL but I have a URL that has JSON data. Is there a function that I can use to download the data in the JSON URL?

ie. How can I download the data in this [JSON URL](http://ts1.travian.com/ajax.php?cmd=mapPositionData&data%5Bx%5D=0&data%5By%5D=0&data%5BzoomLevel%5D=1) .

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether there is a built-in function to do so. But I believe [JsonCpp](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/) may help you to parse json data.